# Relation between eigenvalues and rows or columns of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am wondering about the relation between the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ and it rows or columns. I mean can one say that $\lambda_1$ is related to $r_1$ (first row of $A$) or $c_1$ (first column of $A$)? I know you may ask then what is $\lambda_1$? But the question is, what is the relation between a specific eigenvalue of a matrix and a column or a row of the matrix?

If there is a relation between rows (or columns) and eigenvalues. Say that: $\lambda_1$ corresponds to $r_1$. If i take the transpose of A, since eigenvalues still are same, can I still say $\lambda_1$ corresponds to $r_1'$ (first row of $A'$).

This might be a little strange question, but i appreciate for any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down (I'm going for more of an intuitive answer here):

When you multiply a matrix $M$ and a vector $v_i$, you take each row of the matrix and do an inner product with the vector to get the elements of the resulting vector $v_o$ -- so row 1 of $M$ times $v_i$ gets you the first element in $v_o$, row 2 of $M$ gets you the second element of $v_o$, etc.

If $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $M$, then multiplying them will give you a $v_o$ that is effectively $v_i$ times a constant, where the constant is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector.

Since the *whole* output vector ($v_o$) is a scalar multiple of the input vector ($v_i$), the eigenvalues cannot be directly related to specific rows of $M$; each element of $v_o$ only "interacted" with a single row of $M$ -- a different row for each element -- during the multiplication, but *every* element of $v_o$ was scaled by the *same* (eigen)value from the original elements in $v_i$.

As for the columns, *every* column of $M$ affects *every* element of the output vector, so how do we separate out the distinct eigenvalues?

The whole of $M$ can be seen as a transformation. For certain vectors, the transformation only ends up scaling that vector -- this is just a result of applying a particular transformation to a particular vector.

Answer (score 1):

Well, spectral life of matrices is not that straightforward and simple, unfortunately.

For a given (square) matrix $M$, one can find an *equivalent* matrix $M'=B^{-1}MB$ for some invertible $B$ matrix, which is in [**Jordan normal form**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), that is, *almost diagonal*. And its diagonal elements (say, columns as you wish) are just the eigenvalues.

And, practically this $B$ matrix contains among its columns one eigenvector for each eigenvalue (counted with multiplicity)..

Considering columns or rows corresponds to the question, from which direction we want the matrix to *act* on vectors. Meant, $Mv$ can be written for column vector $v$, and $uM$ for row vector $u$...